# How to show "Sub domain - block" updates from sidebar to my "Main domain"?

Tags: domain-access

I am showing "Recent Blogs" in sidebar second for Subdomain (i.e., for ex:- blog.example.com). Here block is displaying with blog titles with recent blog posts. when we click on any link it shows the particular blog page.

I kept custom block with recent blog posts in my main website (i.e., for ex:- example.com), but I don't want to use this database for recent blog posts. i.e., It should connect to the blog posts related to sub-domian website. If any blog post updated in "blog.example.com", it sholud show in main website "example.com" also. when we click on any blogpost it will 
redirect to sub-domain (blog.example.com). Can we do this by editing settings.php? i.e., As like "Single Sign On"... Here Users table is taking from master domain. If we can do with this please reply me the changes in code for blog posts similar to below code (OR) Please reply me the possible working solutions.. Thanks in advance.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'drupal2',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => array(
        'default' => 'drupal2.',
        'users' => 'drupal1.',
        'sessions' => 'drupal1.',
        'role' => 'drupal1.',
        'authmap' => 'drupal1.',
        'users_roles' => 'drupal1.',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```